# Converting dateTime to an int

Tags: java, android, datetime, int

I am having the user enter the date and the time.  I need to changed it to an int to fit in the sqlight DB.  I have tried parsing it to a string and then to an int, but that doesn't work any ideas?

```
     Time newTime= new Time();
    newTime.hour=fmtTime.HOUR0_FIELD;
    newTime.minute=fmtTime.MINUTE_FIELD;
    newTime.monthDay=fmtDate.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH_FIELD;
    newTime.month=fmtDate.MONTH_FIELD;
    newTime.year=fmtDate.YEAR_FIELD;
    int currentTime=newTime.get;//how would I convert newTime to an int?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
currentTime = (int) (newTime.toMillis() / 1000L);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a Time object to a number of seconds since the epoch (in unix terms) you can simply get the number of milliseconds:

```
newTime.toMillis() / 1000
```